# expl3: wrong result with \l_keys_key_tl and \text_titlecase_first:n

Tags: expl3, l3keys

The following code tries to process the argument as keys, and store the one unknown key's name into a token list. What is confusing to me is that, if, say, the argument is `text`, when I ask the macro to show the stored token list, it correctly shows `text`, but when I try to `\text_titlecase_first:n` it, the result becomes `TEXT` instead of `Text`.

If I change `\l_keys_key_tl` directly to the text `text`, then everything works fine. Is this because that I am using `\l_keys_key_tl` wrongly?

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l__mymodule_text_tl
\keys_define:nn { my-keys }
  {
    , unknown .code:n = { \tl_set:No \l__mymodule_text_tl { \l_keys_key_tl } }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \TestFunction { m }
  {
    \keys_set:nn { my-keys } { #1 }
    \l__mymodule_text_tl\par
    \text_titlecase_first:n { \l__mymodule_text_tl }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\TestFunction{text}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If there are no defined keys and you want to execute code on the input, use `\keyval_parse:NNn` (or `\keyval_parse:nnn`) instead of setting up an unknown handler and firing up `\keys_set:nn`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The titlecase code currently determines whether it has found a 'letter' based on catcode. As key names are detokenized, none of them are letters and so the 'text' has not started. This behaviour is controllable using `\l_text_titlecase_check_letter_bool`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l__mymodule_text_tl
\keys_define:nn { my-keys }
  {
    , unknown .code:n = { \tl_set_eq:NN \l__mymodule_text_tl \l_keys_key_tl }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \TestFunction { m }
  {
    \keys_set:nn { my-keys } {#1}
    \text_titlecase_first:n { \l__mymodule_text_tl }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\TestFunction{text}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\bool_set_false:N \l_text_titlecase_check_letter_bool
\ExplSyntaxOff
\TestFunction{text}
\end{document}
```

(It is possible that this code will be revised to use Unicode general category to avoid catcode impacts, but that is not yet decided.)

Comment: May I ask if there is a normal version of `\l_keys_key_tl` so as to record the key name as usual text? In my actual usage, the command receives keys like `variant=..., <prep>`, where the unknown key would be interpreted as the "preposition" for cross referencing. I find that with `\l_keys_key_tl`, even setting `\l_text_titlecase_check_letter_bool` to false won't fix all issues, sometimes I still get all uppercased text.

Comment: @Jinwen Key names are programming identifiers, not 'text', and we store them from the start detokenized. As such, they should not be used for typesetting (other than in diagnostics).

Comment: @Jinwen there are other key=value parsers that would allow this usage (shameless advertisement for my own `expkv`).